# ArcCatalog crashes in customize mode

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, arccatalog, customize-mode

I have massive problems with my ArcGIS 10.3.1 installation since a week. My ArcMap crashes on start without any message. ArcCatalog crashes in opening the customize-dialog opening the tab commands.

Last thing i have done before the problem orccurs was to install the odac because i want to create an ole db connection to an oracle-service.

Now i deinstalled the odac, cleared the user-templates(mxt and gxt a.s.o), i deinstaled arcgis, cleaned up the registry, installed arcgis 10.3 again, installed arcgis 10.3.1 but nothing helped. My Win 7 is up to date, what can i do, i'm very frustrated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yesterday I could solve this problem, there was something wrong with my python installation. After deinstallation of QGis i had removed the folder OSGEO4W. Yesterday I installed OSGEO4W and Python and ArcGIS does its work again.

Answer (score 0):

You are working with ArcGIS 10.3.1 for Desktop so presumably your license is maintained.

Consequently, my recommendation with the symptoms that you describe, and your stated frustration, is to contact your local Esri Technical Support.

The quote below comes from our [Help Center](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> **We are not a GIS Software Support Site**. We encourage you to seek official routes for support for specific issues you may have.